# Vim Regex Substitution Negative Lookbehind Is Canceling Capture Group

Tags: regex, vim, substitution, neovim

Say I have the following text

```
-o
-O
--object
`-o`
`-O`
```

I would like for it to be

```
`-o`
`-O`
--object
`-o`
`-O`
```

To do this, I tried using the following regex

```
%s/\v(`)@<!(-(--)@<!o|-O)/`\1`/g
```

however, what ended up happening was the following

```
``
``
--object
`-o`
`-O`
```

For some reason the `\1`, referring to the capture group of `(-(--)@<!o|-O)` is being ignored. What is strange is that if I remove `` (`)@<! `` I get the following

```
`-o`
`-O`
--object
``-o``
``-O``
```

So the regex is sound, but for some reason the initial negative lookbehind is messing with the capture group. I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer which appears to be an incorrect back reference. I should be using `\2` instead of `\1`. See the following

```
%s/\v(`)@<!(-(--)@<!o|-O)/`\2`/g
                            ^ Used to be a '1'
```

I was unaware that vim regex counted regex lookarounds as capture groups.

Please see my uncertainties about this mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: What I am unsure of, however, is why the substituted text was just `\`\``. If `\1` is referencing the `(\`)` then how come the substituted text is not `\`\`\``?

Comment: Is the answer to my above question that since its a negative lookbehind, it captures when the character is not present, and as such the character that is captured is a null character?

Answer (score 0):

Using global command:

```
:g/^-[a-z]/s/.*/`&`

^ .............. start of line
- .............. dash
[a-z] .......... folowed by a to z
```